# Why is iconutil generating chopped up images on retina display?

Tags: xcode, macos, iconutil

I have an `.iconset` which can be found [here](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst/tree/master/Amethyst/Amethyst.iconset). Building a binary with Xcode results in an icon that looks like

[image: chopped up icon]

Generating a `.icns` file directly using `iconutil` results in the same thing. Everything but the full resolution asset look weirdly chopped up on retina screens, but displays fine on non-retina screens. Converting the generated `.icns` back to an `.iconset` gives me the chopped up assets instead of the original assets.

Anyone have any idea as to what might be going wrong here?

Comment: http://v.gd/xcassets < (those are your icons in an asset catalog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, though I'm not exactly sure what caused it.

I generated the app icon using Gimp. I believe when I first generated the icon I created a 1024x1024 icon and then scaled it down using Preview. I just regenerated all of the assets by scaling and exporting all through Gimp. Now the assets look fine. Presumably some information was lost in Preview's scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put them in an [**Asset Catalog**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1) to get all the resolutions to show up correctly. If you don't migrate them into one you can manually edit your applications .plist file, although there shouldn't be any compelling reason you would need to go that route.

Reference: [Mac Developer Library: Asset Catalog Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1)

[image]

Select Targets > Your App > General > App Icons

Comment: Unfortunately using an asset catalog results in the same behavior. I believe that `actool` (the utility that compiles asset catalogs) is probably internally using `iconutil` to compile the app icon.